# Wait until translation completed - Ngx Translate

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, ngx-translate

I'm working on a project that need to translate a text in typescript file using ngx translate library but I want to wait until the translation complete before load the component. I tried the following code but didn't works.

```
console.log('start');
this.lables = await this.translateService.stream('Labels').toPromise().then(res => res);
console.log(lables , 'check translation');  // it show nothing 
console.log('end');
```

2nd Method :

```
console.log('start');
this.lables = await this.translateService.stream('Labels').pipe(take(1)).toPromise().then(res => res);
console.log(lables , 'check translation');  // it show "Labels" as a string.
console.log('end');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can console.log inside the evaluated promise by using only then without the await

```
console.log('start');
this.translateService.stream('Labels').toPromise().then(labels => {
  console.log(labels, 'check translation');
  console.log('end');
});
```

Comment: I tried and It shows Labels as a string and not the content

Comment: you will need to investigate your  ```this.translateService.stream('Labels') ``` what does it return?

Comment: it should return a json object contains list of translated words

Comment: does it do that? consoe.log it

Comment: well, then you need to see how to properly get that object by using this.translateService.stream('Labels')